# How to obtain a pointer(?) to a BitCast instruction?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

let's assume I have a simple IR that looks like this:

```
%1 = alloca i8*, align 8
%2 = bitcast i8* %1 to i8*
%3 = load i8*, i8** %1, align 8
```

So I am trying to replace the use of `%1` in `%3 = load i8*, %1, align 8` with the instruction `%2 = bitcast i8* %1 to i8*`. I understand how to replace using the [`replaceUsesWithIf`](https://mlir.llvm.org/doxygen/classmlir_1_1Value.html#a3bd2c23a2e260ab25fdbf8b885bd594f) API, but the problem is that after using that API, I end up with the following

`%3 = load i8*, i8* %2, align 8`

This is incorrect because the `type` that I am `load`ing from should be `i8**` rather than `i8*`.

Therefore, I *think* I need to obtain a pointer to a `BitCast` instruction. I believe one way could be to create a new `BitCast` instruction of `%2 = bitcast i8* %1 to i8*` instruction with `i8**` type?

Here is my attempt at doing so:

```
for (auto &Inst : BB) {
        if (auto bitcast_I = dyn_cast<BitCastInst>(&Inst)) {
           /* %2 = bitcast i8* %1 to i8* will be matched */
            
           Value *bitcast_v = bitcastI->getOperand(0);
           BitCastInst *newBitcast = new BitCastInst(bitcast_v, 
                       PointerType::get(IntegerType::get(context, 8), 0), "newBit", bitcast_I);
        }
```

Unfortunately, what I attempted above doesn't yield the correct code, but at the same time, I'm not even too sure whether this is right, so I wanted to ask whether this approach makes sense.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but [Instruction::setOperand()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1User.html#a5fa9b8e1842b354f64c1ba6be0a4a17f) may be the function you want. You can't ever get a pointer to a bitcast, because its result is in a CPU register, and pointers point to main memory.

Comment: Your link to `replaceUsesWithIf` is in MLIR, which is a totally different subproject of LLVM. The API you probably want is `replaceAllUsesWIth` or "RAUW" for short, that allows you to replace all uses of one Value with another, as long as the types match.

Comment: Your values have different types, `%1` being `i8**` and `%2` being `i8*` so you cannot replace one with the other. If you want to make your load use the bitcast in `%2`, then you will need to delete the load and build a new LoadInst.

Comment: Hello @NickLewycky, yes you are absolutely correct. Coincidentally last night, I learned exactly what you suggested and applied it to solve the issue. If you wish to put your suggestion as a solution, I will accept the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values have different types, %1 being i8** and %2 being i8* so you cannot replace one with the other. If you want to make your load use the bitcast in %2, then you will need to delete the load and build a new LoadInst.